# How can we get the requesting client timezone in web api?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

**How can we get the requesting client timezone in web API?**

Can we get it by HttpContext.Current??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determine-a-users-timezone